# Unable to calculate and display TB in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a javascript code which displays different values based on arrow moving. I can't explain precisely so please see image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0kqK.jpg

I have managed to change everything except number of bandwidth. on moving arrow bandwidth remains same i.e. 2TB

```
<div class="sliderCon">
<div class="slider-wrap slider-container">
<input readonly="" class="value" onchange="s.setValue(parseInt(this.value))" name="hvalue" id="hvalue" value="0" type="hidden">
<div tabindex="1" id="slider1" class="horizontal dynamic-slider-control">
<input id="sliderinput1" class="slider-input" value="0">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var packages = [
[ 50, 1, 25600, 2097152, 15.00, '#/cart.php?a=add&pid=59', ''],
[ 100, 2, 51200, 4194304, 30.00, '#/cart.php?a=add&pid=21', ''],
[ 100, 4, 102400, 8388608, 50.00, '#/cart.php?a=add&pid=22', '']
];
function _(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
var s = new Slider(_("slider1"), _("sliderinput1"));
var old_value = 0;
s.onchange = function () {
new_value = s.getValue();
_('line').style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
_('line').style.backgroundPosition = (parseInt(_('handle').style.left) - 0) + 'px 0px';
//_('p' + old_value).setAttribute("class", "");
for(var i=2; i>=0;i--)
{
if(i > new_value)
_('p' + i).setAttribute("class", "");
else
_('p' + i).setAttribute("class", "active");
}
old_value = new_value;
_('hvalue').value = new_value;
_('cpu').innerHTML = packages[new_value][0] + ' %';
_('ram').innerHTML = packages[new_value][1] + ' GB';
_('disk').innerHTML = parseInt(packages[new_value][2] / 1024) + ' GB';
_('bandwidth').value = new_value;
_('price1').innerHTML = '$' + (packages[new_value][4]).toFixed(2);
_('odernow').href = packages[new_value][5];
_('compare').href = packages[new_value][6];
};
window.onresize = function () {
s.recalculate();
};
</script>
<div class="clr"></div>
<ul class="sliderStyle">
<li class="NoBorderLt server01"><a id="p0" onclick="s.setValue(0)" href="javascript:%20return;">Starter VPS</a></li>
<li class="server02"><a id="p1" onclick="s.setValue(1)" href="javascript:%20return;">Developer VPS</a></li>
<li class="server03"><a id="p2" onclick="s.setValue(2)" href="javascript:%20return;">Executive VPS</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="clr"></div>
<div class="sliderStyle02Con">
<ul class="sliderStyle02">
<li class="cpu"><strong>CPU Usage</strong><br>
<span class="sliderTextStyle" id="cpu">50%</span></li>
<li class="ram"><strong>RAM</strong><br>
<span class="sliderTextStyle" id="ram">1 GB</span></li>
<li class="space"><strong>Disk Space</strong><br>
<span class="sliderTextStyle" id="disk">25 GB</span></li>
<li class="network1"><strong>Bandwidth</strong><br>
<span class="sliderTextStyle" id="bandwidth"> 2 TB</span></li>
<li class="cost"><span class="sliderTextStyle2" id="price1">$10.00</span><br>Monthly Cost</li>
</ul>
<div class="clr"></div>
<div class="sliderBtn"> <a id="odernow" href="#/cart.php?gid=4">Order Now</a> </div>

</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
s.setValue(0);
</script>   
</div>
```

Comment: What is the element with ID 'bandwidth'?

Comment: Could we see the HTML too?

Comment: Yeah, that could help

Comment: Since you're assigning something to its .value, I assume it's an `<input>` or a `<select>`.

Comment: @Neha You should format your code before putting it on stackoverflow

Comment: @Bálint i have formatted, haven't i ?

Comment: @NehaAgra do you indent your code?

Comment: @MauricePerry done this _('bandwidth').innerHTML = new_value; it does change the value. But values are not expected. First it shows 0 then 1 then 2. My sequence is 2tb, 4tb and 8tb.

Comment: @NehaAgra see my update below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since #bandwith is a <span> element, you can change its content with .innerHtml, not .value.

UPDATE:
So I guess you should write something like:

```
_('bandwidth').innerHTML = Math.round(packages[new_value][3] / (1024*1024)) + " TB";
```