# cannot get values of elements by class name

Tags: javascript, html

I create a lot of `h1` whose class names are the same as below.

```
<h1 class="h1">One</h1>
<h1 class="h1">Two</h1>
<h1 class="h1">Three</h1>
<h1 class="h1">Four</h1>
```

Also create a button which will show values of these elements

```
<button id="button">Show</button>
```

And by clicking I want to show all the values of the elements with class "h1"

```
const button = document.getElementById('button');
var h1 = document.getElementsByClassName('h1');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    for (var i = 0; i<=h1.lenght; i++){
        alert(h1[i].value);
    }
});
```

But nothing is showing.

Comment: You have a typo in `lenght`. Also, `<h1>` elements don't have a `value` attribute. Form elements do. Finally, since arrays are zero-indexed in JavaScript, you want `<`, not `<=`

Comment: `<h1>` does not have a `value`. It does have `innerHTML`. `value` is restricted to input-type elements.

Comment: There has to be a dupetarget for @connexo's observation... (For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745293/find-a-value-of-table-cell, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759529/unable-to-calculate-and-display-tb-in-javascript)

Comment: Probably. If only this site had decent search functionality.

Comment: Also where did you include the script, in the head tag ? If so you will have to wait for the DOM to be ready to bind the events. Or you can include the script just before the end of the body closing tag.

Comment: @connexo: :-) Found a couple...

Comment: Event if the `<h1>` tag has no `value` attribute, we are atleast expected to see `undefined` in the alert. @connexo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to calculate and display TB in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759529/unable-to-calculate-and-display-tb-in-javascript)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your first find is actually a reverse dupe :D

Comment: @connexo: I don't follow you. The questions are both using `value` where they should use `innerHTML`...? Of course, now the question's been edited to use `input` instead of `h1`... Moving target.

Comment: In the first dupe you linked OP tried to read stuff using `innerHTML` from table cells while what he needed was `value` from a `input`s inside  those table cells.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This should definitely be marked as a duplicate, not put on hold due to being off-topic. I have rolled back OPs edit since he introduced additional errors with the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo at length and also if you use <= it will go out of range so you should use < and .innerHTML for your original One, after the edit if you want to get value of inputs , you should use .value

```
const button = document.getElementById('button');

var h1 = document.getElementsByClassName('h1');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   for (var i = 0; i<h1.length; i++){
     console.log(h1[i].innerHTML);

}
});
```

Comment: @AL-zami  i < h1.length-1 would leave the last one out no ?  only 0, 1 , 2 will be show.

Comment: if I have an input instead of h1? How to get value ?

Comment: @Mr.Chingis var inputValue = document.getElementById('elementId').value;  for input you can use .value